# Triangulation of a N-gon

Tags: combinatorics, triangulation, catalan-numbers

In how many ways can a regular n-gon be divided into $n-2$ triangles if different orientations are **not** to be counted separately?

I have counted the ways for different n-gons and found that up to a pentagon the answer is 1 but then for $n=6,7,8,9$ the answers are $4,6,19,49$. I'm supposed to express this in terms of the Catalan numbers but don't know how to do that.

Comment: Looks like [OEIS sequence A0016883](https://oeis.org/A001683).  See formulas and links there.

Comment: Repeat of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1986709/triangulations-of-n-gon ?

Comment: I tried to provide relevant readings and an OEIS entry at the earlier link.

Comment: $C_{n-2/n} + C_{n/2-1}/2 + (2/3)*C_{n/3-1}$