# Triangulated n-gon

Tags: combinatorics, triangulation, catalan-numbers

How many ways are there to triangulate a regular convex n-gon, if two
triangulations are regarded as being the same if they can be made to coincide by a rotation of the polygon?

I was asked to express this in terms of the Catalan numbers and I got $G_n = \frac{C_{n-2}}{2} + \frac{C_{\frac{n}{2}-1}}{2} +\frac{2C_{\frac{n}{3}-1}}{3}$ where Cn is the Catalan number and if the subscript is not an integer than it is omitted.

Now I have to try and prove that my expression $G_n$ is true but this is where I run into trouble. I tried induction and the inductive step was where it all fell apart.

Comment: I see you've posted this question twice: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1986709/triangulations-of-n-gon/2122930.  If you wanted to add information to the question you should have edited the original one, not open a second one.

Answer (score 2):

Consulting  the  paper  by  Richard  Guy *Dissecting  a  polygon  into
triangles* and  using a somewhat  similar notation we  introduce $D_n$
which  is  $C_{n-2}$  where  $C_n$  is  the  Catalan  number  $$C_n  =
\frac{1}{n+1} {2n\choose n}$$ when $n$  is a positive integer at least
two  and zero  otherwise.  We  then have  consult  e.g. [Wikipedia  on
Catalan   Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)  that
the number of triangulations of the convex $n$-gon is given by $D_n.$

Now make  the following observation  concerning rotational symmetry
of  the  triangulations  of   the  regular  $n$-gon.   There  are  two
possibilities for the center of the $n$-gon, either it is located on a
diagonal  which is  in fact  a diameter  or it  is inside  one  of the
triangles. In the  first case we can have symmetry only  if we map the
diameter to itself by a $180$ degree rotation. Call the count of these
$F_n$.   In the  second case  we have  symmetry only  if  the triangle
containing  the center  is equilateral  and we  have two  rotations by
$120$ and $240$ degrees fixing  that triangle. Call the count of these
$R_n.$ Finally introduce $U_n$, triangulations having no symmetry. The
desired quantity is then given by

$$E_n = F_n + R_n + U_n.$$

We have by inspection that

$$F_n = D_{n/2+1} \quad\text{and}\quad 
R_n = D_{n/3+1}.$$

Furthermore

$$D_n = \frac{n}{2} F_n + \frac{n}{3} R_n
+ n U_n$$

where we have computed the sizes of the respective orbits.
This yields

$$U_n = \frac{1}{n} D_n - \frac{1}{2} F_n - \frac{1}{3} R_n$$

so that

$$E_n = \frac{1}{n} D_n + \frac{1}{2} F_n + \frac{2}{3} R_n$$

or

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
E_n = \frac{1}{n} D_n 
+ \frac{1}{2} D_{n/2+1} + \frac{2}{3} D_{n/3+1}.}$$

This yields the sequence

$$1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 6, 19, 49, 150, 442,
\\ 1424, 4522, 14924, 49536, 167367, \ldots$$

which  points us  to  [OEIS A001683](https://oeis.org/A001683),  where
detailed references await.  (We have started at index  $2$ rather than
$3$ to match the convention that the OEIS uses.)