# Pairs of Beads on a Ring

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups, permutations

I would like to count the number of inequivalent ways to arrange $2N$ colored beads on a ring if there are $N$ colors and $2$ beads of each color.

By "inequivalent' I mean inequivalent under (1) rotating the ring (2) flipping the ring (3) exchanging any two beads of the same color.

Answer (score 2):

We can  answer this quite  easily using the Polya  Enumeration Theorem
and the  cycle index  $Z(D_{2N})$ of the  dihedral group. We  will not
derive  this cycle  index here  but it  can be  worked out  from first
principles without too much difficulty. We then have for the answer

$$[A_1^2 A_2^2 \cdots A_N^2]  Z(D_{2N})
\left(A_1+A_2+\cdots+A_N\right).$$

The cycle index is

$$Z(D_{2N}) = \frac{1}{4N} \sum_{d|2N} \varphi(d) a_d^{2N/d}
+ \frac{1}{4} a_1^2 a_2^{N-1} + \frac{1}{4} a_2^N.$$

where we have  contributions from the cycle index  of the cyclic group
and from two types of  reflections (axis passes through opposite slots
or edges).

As we only have two instances  of each color and we substitute $a_d
= A_1^d + A_2^d + \cdots + A_N^d$ the contribution reduces to

$$\frac{1}{4N} \varphi(1) a_1^{2N}
+ \frac{1}{4N} \varphi(2) a_2^{N}
+ \frac{1}{4} a_1^2 a_2^{N-1} + \frac{1}{4} a_2^N$$

which works out to

$$\frac{1}{4N} a_1^{2N}
+ \frac{N+1}{4N} a_2^{N}
+ \frac{1}{4} a_1^2 a_2^{N-1}.$$

Do the substitution to get

$$\frac{1}{4N} (A_1+A_2+\cdots+A_N)^{2N}
+ \frac{N+1}{4N} (A_1^2+A_2^2+\cdots+A_N^2)^{N}
\\ + \frac{1}{4} (A_1+A_2+\cdots+A_N)^2 
(A_1^2+A_2^2+\cdots+A_N^2)^{N-1}.$$

Extracting coefficients now yields

$$\frac{1}{4N} {2N\choose 2,2,\ldots, 2}
+ \frac{N+1}{4N} {N\choose 1,1,\ldots, 1}
+ \frac{1}{4} {N\choose 1} {N-1\choose 1,1,\ldots, 1}.$$

This simplifies to

$$\frac{1}{4N} \frac{(2N)!}{2^N}
+ \frac{N+1}{4} (N-1)! + \frac{1}{4} N!$$

and we obtain the closed form

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{4N} \frac{(2N)!}{2^N} + \frac{2N+1}{4} (N-1)!.}$$

This yields the sequence

$$1, 2, 11, 171, 5736, 312240, 24327000, 2554072920, 
\\ 347351195520, 59397023589120, \ldots $$

which  points  us  to  [OEIS A120445](https://oeis.org/A120445)  where
additional    material    awaits   (and    the    above   result    is
confirmed). (Observe that they use  the term necklace when we actually
have a bracelet.)

The following memory  efficient Perl script can be  used to compute
the first six values of the sequence (output matches result from PET).

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

sub recurse {
    my ($n, $slots, $sofar, $orbref) = @_;

    my $rest = scalar(@$slots);

    if($rest == 0){
        my @perm = (-1) x (2*$n);

        my $color = 1;

        map {
            $perm[$sofar->[2*$_]-1] = $color;
            $perm[$sofar->[1+2*$_]-1] = $color;

            $color++;
        } (0..$n-1);

        my (%orbit, $key);

        for(my $rot = 0; $rot < 2*$n; $rot++){
            my @rotact = ();

            push @rotact, 
            @perm[$rot..(2*$n-1)],
            @perm[0..($rot)-1];

            $key = join('-', @rotact);
            $orbit{$key} = 1;

            if($rot % 2 == 0){
                my @reflact1 = reverse @rotact;

                $key = join('-', @reflact1);
                $orbit{$key} = 1;

                my @reflact2; 

                push @reflact2, 
                @reflact1[1..(2*$n-1)],
                $reflact1[0];

                $key = join('-', @reflact2);
                $orbit{$key} = 1;
            }
        }

        $key = join('|', sort(keys(%orbit)));
        $orbref->{$key} = 1;

        return;
    }

    for(my $p=0; $p < $rest; $p++){
        for(my $q = $p+1; $q < $rest; $q++){
            push @$sofar, $slots->[$p], $slots->[$q];

            my @data;

            push @data, 
            @$slots[0..$p-1],
            @$slots[$p+1..$q-1],
            @$slots[$q+1..$rest-1];

            recurse($n, \@data, $sofar, $orbref);

            splice @$sofar, -2, 2;
        }
    }

    1;
}

 MAIN: {
     my $n = shift || 5;

     my %orbits;

     recurse($n, [1..2*$n], [], \%orbits);

     print scalar(keys(%orbits));
     print "\n";

     1;
}
```

**Addendum.**  We can also  do this  from first  principles without
using  PET.  Introduce the  total count  of bracelets  before applying
symmetry  and call  it $D_N.$  Let $R_N$  be the  bracelets  that have
rotational symmetry,  $F_N$ the  ones that have  reflectional symmetry
with an axis passing through  opposite slots, $G_N$ the ones that have
reflectional symmetry with an axis passing through opposite edges. Put
$U_N$ for  the ones with  no symmetry. We  are thus interested  in the
quantity

$$E_N = R_N + F_N + G_N + U_N.$$

It  is not  difficult  to see  that  with $N$  sufficiently large  the
bracelets with rotational symmetry do not have reflectional symmetries
which would otherwise require inclusion-exclusion.

Now we have $R_N =  \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{N} N!$ and $F_N = \frac{1}{2}
N \times (N-1)!$ and $G_N = \frac{1}{2} N!.$

Observe also that when computing the sizes of the orbits we find

$$D_N = {2N\choose 2,2,\ldots,2} =
2 N R_N + 2 N  F_N + 2 N G_N
+  4 N U_N$$

which implies

$${2N\choose 2,2,\ldots,2} =
2N \times \frac{1}{2} (1 + 2N) (N-1)!
+  4 N U_N \\ = (1+2N) \times N! + 4 N U_N $$

so that

$$E_N = \frac{1}{2} (1+2N) (N-1)!
+ \frac{1}{4N} {2N\choose 2,2,\ldots,2}
- \frac{1+2N}{4} (N-1)!
\\ = \frac{1}{4N} \frac{(2N)!}{2^N}
+ \frac{1+2N}{4} (N-1)!$$

as before.

A reference for  this technique may be found  at the following [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020438/).

Comment: I can't single out your mistake, but my numerics agrees with the result of KaliMa, and with https://oeis.org/A137729

Comment: Look carefully at that entry -- it says it counts symmetries up to rotations. As you say you require flips in your post I took it to mean symmetries up to rotations and reflections, which is what I computed. (Flips are a form of reflections.) Considering what I presented above doing rotations only is very straightforward -- use the cycle index of the cyclic group which omits the two terms for the two  types of reflections and has $2N$ permutations.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** Start by considering the ways to arrange your beads in a straight line.

Then it will become easier to know how to avoid counting repeated combinations.

Answer (score 0):

First imagine the beads in a straight line.

There are $(2N)!$ ways to arrange the beads if we don't care about duplicates, mirrors, etc.

But now we want to divide out the stuff we don't want.

Every pair of beads that have the same color have been double-counted. In other words (Green1) (Green2) is the same as (Green2) (Green1). So for each pair of colors we divide by $2$. There are $N$ colors so we divide by $2^N$.

At this point we add $N!$ for a reason I am not sure about yet. Maybe someone else can offer an explanation in a separate answer.

Now we divide by $2$ to account for the fact that any layout can be flipped over into a mirror layout.

Finally we divide by $N$ to account for the fact that we could start the chain in $N$ different spots, but we want to consider all of these as being the same ring.

$$\frac{\frac{(2N)!}{2^N} + N!}{2N}$$

Also see https://oeis.org/A137729

This is also a specific case ($n=2$) of "Number of distinct $k$-colored necklaces with $n$ beads per color" where

$$ A(n,k) = \sum_{d | n} \frac{\phi(n/d)(kd)!}{(d!)^kkn}$$

Comment: That was my answer too, but it fails for $N=2$ (in fact, it doesn't even resolve to an integer in this case). Should probably divide by $N$ instead of by $2N$, though not quite sure how to explain why.

Comment: @barakmanos I wrote a program to compute the result directly and the numbers lead to https://oeis.org/A137729 with equation $a(n) = ((2n)!/2^n + n!) / (2n)$ which means after removing the color-pair duplicates, $n!$ is added first before we divide by $2$ for mirrors and $N$ for rings.

Comment: For some configurations, rotation/flipping gives the same result one would get from exchanging all pairs of same-colored beads. If we shift "green1 red1 green2 red2" by 2, for instance, we get "green2 red2 green1 red1", which we would also get by exchanging the two beads of each pair. Same if we flip "green1 red1 red2 green2". Maybe the + n! in your numerator takes this into account?