# Counting problem about polygon triangulations

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, combinatorial-geometry, triangulation, polya-counting-theory

I have the following question about triangulations (by non-intersecting diagonals, and edges) of regular polygons.

What is the number of triangulations of a regular n-gon, up to all symmetry (i.e. the whole dihedral group)?

For instance, if one discards symmetry, then the answer is the (n-2) Catalan number. If one only considers rotational symmetry, answer is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1986709/triangulations-of-n-gon).

The obvious approach is to apply Burnside/Polya, but I don't see a clear pattern on the cases that would show up for an arbitrary n.

I would like to know where to go from here.

Thanks!!

Comment: This is OEIS [A000207](https://oeis.org/A000207), and is discussed clearly in J. Moon and L. Moser, [“Triangular Dissections of N-Gons”](https://doi.org/10.4153/CMB-1963-017-0), *Canadian Mathematical Bulletin* **6** (1963), 175–178.

Comment: @hoboonsuan thanks!!

Comment: @hoboonsuan why not convert your comment into an answer?  OP seems happy with it.